firewalld destination ip constraint difficulty and incorrect model?
I have a centos server with 5 public IPs.  When I set it up I used firewalld commands like firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=1666/tcp to open a port.  I have a bunch of these ports I need to open, and thinking about it more recently, I would like the various ports to only be open on the IPs that the services are listening on, which seems like a normal way to think about tightening up the machine's security.  In other words, if port 1666 is only really used by a service listening on IP1, then having the port open for connections to IP2:1666 seems not great.
However, it appears to be kind of messy to restrict destination IPs with firewall-cmd.  It's easy with iptables, but the fact that it seems to require rich rules or hacks to service xml files (the two ways I've found to do it with firewalld) implies it is not a normal thing people do.
Is there some other way I should be doing this?  Should I not worry about needing to use a rich rule even though it seems way messier than just the --add-port command and just write the rich rule version like this?
Thanks for any insight here, I was surprised there wasn't just a destination version of --add-source even if it meant I needed to make a zone per IP.
